# Custom component property binding triggers multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have noticed that when you use a custom component with a input property and you bind a function to it this function is called lots of times.

E.g.

```
<some-tag [random-input]="randomFunction()"></some-tag>
```

and in the class

```
private randomFunction() {
    console.log('Called!');
    return true
}
```

if you run something simple as this you will see in the console a few dozens of 'Called!' logs.
In my project the randomFunction makes a call to the database, so this is pretty anoying.

Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please show code inside randomFunction().

Answer (score 1):

Angular runs this with [every cycle](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f), trying to check for updated value, that's why you see so many messages in the log.

For this reason it is not good practice to have `ts` functions as inputs to component.

You can for example make a call to the server/database in `constructor`, `OnInit` or `OnChanges`, store the result to local variable and make that variable as input to component. Something similar to this:

```
export class MyComp {
   dbResult: any;

   constructor(http: HttpClient) {
     http.get('/my/api/call').subscribe(result => {
       this.dbResult = result;
     });
   }
   ....
}
```

..and in HTML:

`<some-tag [random-input]="dbResult"></some-tag>`

As a sidenote, having that function marked as `private` will eventually fail during `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Angular needs to check if the value has changes otherwise it can't update the value inside the component.